# Am I thinking the AngularJS way?

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to dabble with AngularJS and would like to know if the code that I've put below is inline with the AngularJS way of writing or could something be improved?

**Intention:** Hide the reset button and show it when the user keys-in something in the username and password input boxes. And validate username and show info text when username validation fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Playing with some ng-directives</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
          <label>Username: </label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="username" ng-change="validateUsername();resetRequired()"/>
          <div ng-show="showUsernameInfo"> Username can only contain alphabets and numbers. Nothing else is allowed!</div>

          <label>Password: </label>
          <input type="password" ng-model="password" ng-change="resetRequired()"/>

          <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-hide="hideLoginButton"/>
          <input type="button" value="Reset" ng-hide="hideResetButton"/>
      </div>
</body>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function LoginCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.username = $scope.username || "";
        $scope.password = $scope.password || "";
        $scope.hideResetButton = true;

        $scope.validateUsername = function() {
            $scope.showUsernameInfo = (/([^0-9^a-z^A-Z])/).test($scope.username);
        };

        $scope.resetRequired = function() {
            if ( !angular.isUndefined($scope.username) && !angular.isUndefined($scope.password) ) {
                $scope.hideResetButton = ($scope.username.length==0 && $scope.password.length==0) ? true : false;
            }
        };
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Appreciate your feedback in advance.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Code Review? (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You might also check out the form validation documentation, in particular the section on [Custom Validations](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to  codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks just fine to me, couple of pointers.

I would turn `validateUsername();resetRequired()` into a single method on the scope, reducing clutter in your HTML.

The ternary `? true : false` is redundant, Just use the boolean expression you had in the first place:

```
$scope.hideResetButton = !$scope.username.length && !$scope.password.length
```

<sub>(note that `== 0` is falsy, so you can just check for a truthy length value)</sub>

Lastly, if it were up to me, I'd validate with a watch expression, rather than on change events. This would further clean up your code. Example:

```
$scope.$watch('username + password', function () {
    $scope.invalidateReset();
});
```

The results of the `'username + password'` expression aren't particularly important, we just want the watch to fire if any of the values change. The fact that you won't need to actively add a check on all DOM elements which might change the model, but rather sit back and let the changes come to you, warrant the refactor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and constructive feedback.

Comment: what are the benefits of using `$scope.$watch` here and not `ng-change` events? PS: I am new to AngularJS

Comment: the fact that you won't need to actively add the check to all DOM elements which can change the model, but rather lay back and let the changes come to you.